# This procedure not working

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

This procedure not working

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GETDETAIL 
(@AGE INT, 
 @NAME VARCHAR(50) OUT, 
 @CITY VARCHAR(200) OUT, 
 @MOBILE NUMERIC(20) OUT) 
 AS BEGIN 
 SELECT @NAME=NAME,
        @CITY=CITY,
        @MOBILE=MOBILE 
 FROM ONE 
 WHERE @AGE=AGE END GO
```

ERROR:

> Procedure or function 'GETDETAIL' expects parameter '@NAME', which was not supplied.

Comment: please explain more, then we can help you

Comment: show your `exec` code

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you get two rows with the same age?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not at the procedure it is at the calling. When you call the stored procedure, you need to declare and pass in the required parameter

```
declare  @NAME VARCHAR(50), 
         @CITY VARCHAR(200), 
         @MOBILE NUMERIC(20)

execute GETDETAIL @AGE    = 21, 
                  @NAME   = @NAME OUTPUT, 
                  @CITY   = @CITY OUTPUT, 
                  @MOBILE = @MOBILE OUTPUT

SELECT @NAME, @CITY, @MOBILE
```